# Whither macOS Server 5.3.6 installer?

Tags: osx-server

Until a week ago, I was happily running macOS Server 5.3.6 on High Sierra.

My hard drive failed, resulting in an eternal beachball instead of restarting.  So, I put a clean copy of High Sierra 10.13.6 on an external and rebooted from the new/external startup disk.

Problem:  Neither Server.app, nor the /Library/Server/ directory are present on the clean install.

I need to install Server 5.3.6, the last Server version with support for websites and IMAP mail.

48 hours later I am still searching.

Where can I find a copy of the Server 5.3.6 installer?

Or, should I simply erase the drive and install macOS Sierra [or a given prior macOS version]?

Comment: No proper backups?

Answer (score 1):

Server is a separate app from the OS, that you download from the Mac App Store. It will be listed in the Purchases of the AppleID that was used to buy it.

You could also copy the app from your backup, and it will create all the necessary folders from scratch. (You may want to copy over the contents of /Library/Server, and other files, to restore your server settings.)

Comment: Thanks.  When I attempt to install Server.app from the App store on the High Sierra system, it first offers Server 5.10, and when a download is initiated it switches to the latest Server.app [which doesn't support websites and IMAP mail].

Comment: Normally, the App Store provides the latest version that works with the installed OS. If that's the wrong one, then copy the app from your backup.

Comment: I've notice that some sites list the final "websites and IMAP" version of Server.app is 5.6.3.  I think this is correct, because I also believe that version 5.7 was the version that dropped website and IMAP support.

Comment: Apple have published a 'Migration' document, which provides open source alternatives for each service. Realistically, it's an EOL, unsupported product. https://developer.apple.com/support/downloads/macOS-Server-Service-Migration-Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You want 5.6.3 not 5.3.6. I'm running this version on my Mac mini with High Sierra and it has Mail and Websites support.

If you [go to macOS Server.app on the App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-server/id883878097?mt=12) and try to download it *from a computer running High Sierra*, that is the version that you will get.